# Loop over an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I must do this: to work over string that i will ask to some user:

```
text = "";
arr = ["*****"];
arr2 = [];

text = arr.toString();
for(i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
  arr2.push(text[i]);
}
  ---> arr2 = [*,*,*,*,*] <--- thats what i want!.
```

But i must work with a lot of data like this, so i created and array to content that structured data:

```
  var gems = [
    {
      name: 'Level-1',
      row: {
        r1: '*****',
        r2: '-***-',
        r3: '--*--'
        },
      canPushtoDb: true,
      hideLevel: false,
      status: 1
      //canvas
    },
    {
      name: 'Level-2',
      row: {
        r1: '**-**',
        r2: '-*-*-',
        r3: '-***-',
        },
      canPushtoDb: true,
      hideLevel: false,
      status: 1
      //canvas
    },
    {
      name: 'Level-3',
      row: {
        r1: '*-*-*',
        r2: '**-**',
        r3: '*-*-*'
        },
      canPushtoDb: true,
      hideLevel: true,
      status: 1
      //canvas
    }    

  ];
```

I want to loop within `gems` to convert that string on some kind of array, just like I wrote on the beginning of this question. 
I was looking on an Angular example, which wrap those objects with a `controller`.

But for now I'm far to get my code on some refactored version of his own. I just need some hard-coded function or method like`gems.name[0].row.r1`(this is not working to me!) to get out the object all that I'm working on.

Comment: it would be `gems[0].row.r1` not `gems.name[0].row.r1`

Comment: You should access them like `gems[0].row.r1`. To create array from string's characters: `var arr = str.split('')`;

Comment: You can solve your first parts using `array.fill`. `var arr2 = new Array(tet.length).fill('*')`

Comment: Thank you, @PatrickEvans and Rajesh i can see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterator over gems as such:

```
for(var i = 0; i < gems.length; i++) {
 ...
}
```

You can then loop through the object as such (within your for loop above)

```
$.each(var obj in row) {
 ...Do something with each object found in row
}
```

To access hardcoded object, your issue was `gems.name[0].row.r1`

When it should just be `gems[0].row.r1`

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over the rows with something like this: 
`for(i=0: i<=gems[2].row.length; i++ ){
    arr = "r1: " + r1 + "r2: " + r2 + "r3: " + r3;
}` But it's not working.

Comment: You have to define `r1, r2, r3.` You can do that via `var r1 = gems[2].row.r1`.. etc for all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm doing it this way: `for( arr in arr2){
    text += '<br />' + arr2[arr] + '<br />';
}` . Which present some problems. first, the output shows an `undefined` word as if it was a member on the `object`. And second the editor warm me to wrat the sentence inside the `for` with an `if` statement. I can't undertand both. I defined variables as: `var text;
    var arr;
    var arr2 = gems[0].row;`

Comment: Any way you can get a working example up on jsfiddle? It would be much easier to see what the problem is and how to fix. Might also be good to submit another question, and let me know the link so I can answer it.

Comment: I'm working on some other stuff, but i will put here the link when i ask another.

Comment: You're trying to loop an array when it's an object. `gems[0].row` is an object, not an array. You can access it via `gems[0].row.r1`.

Comment: I can saw that, but i'm trying to iterate trought it. I want to do it inside a loop. I need to check the id of that object then to loop on `row:{}`. So just acces on a 'single' element is not what i want. I think you anderstand better than me. Updated link: http://kopy.io/DDYar. I think is the moment to open another question to keep things clean... I will link it here!

Comment: link to __Part II__ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885822/iterating-over-javascript-object-part-ii/40885986?noredirect=1#comment68987418_40885986

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Patrick Evans, your code is correct except for the fact that `arr2` should be `arr2 = gems[0].row.r1`. Have a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bp7m1yd4/).

Comment: I guess this exact same this has been pointed out by @Patrick Evans in comment section