# Iterating over javascript object- part II

Tags: javascript

hello and thank every one.
Updated link on [kopy.io](http://kopy.io/DDYar).

```
var gems = [...,

    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Level-3',
      row: {
        r1: '*-*-*',
        r2: '**-**',
        r3: '*-*-*'
        },
      canPushtoDb: true,
      hideLevel: true,
      status: 1
      //canvas
    }    

  ];
```

Now i'm trying to iterate over some object like this:

```
    var text;
    var arr;
    var arr2 = gems[0].row;


for( arr in arr2){
    text += '<br />' + arr2[arr] + '<br />';
}
```

But is not working completly:

[image]

```
//* If i will do a kind of graphic map:
// var something = * * * * *  <--- row1
//                 * * * * *  <--- row2
//                 * * * * *  <--- row3
// somthing = [x][y]
```

So i'm keeping things on `gems[]` array, easy to edit/change/modify.
Thats realy the problem because in other way i'd must to implement a
kind of function on each level. 
I need a way to iterate over 'row' member after check on 'id' or 'name'
key value.

I'm confused because i can acces individualy on each member like: `gems[2].name ---> Level-3` or `gems[1].row.r2 ---> -***-`. But it is not
what i want. I searching for a loop that after check on some 'value' 
iterate trought 'row' member. for example: if `level == id` then loop on
`gems[i].row`. But i can't find the way.

```js
var gems = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Level-1',
    row: {
      r1: '*****',
      r2: '-***-',
      r3: '--*--'
    },
    canPushtoDb: true,
    hideLevel: false,
    status: 1
      //canvas
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Level-2',
    row: {
      r1: '**-**',
      r2: '-*-*-',
      r3: '-***-',
    },
    canPushtoDb: true,
    hideLevel: false,
    status: 1
      //canvas
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Level-3',
    row: {
      r1: '*-*-*',
      r2: '**-**',
      r3: '*-*-*'
    },
    canPushtoDb: true,
    hideLevel: true,
    status: 1
      //canvas
  }

];


var text;
var arr;
var arr2 = gems[0].row;


for (arr in arr2) {
  text += '<br />' + arr2[arr] + '<br />';
}
document.write(text);
```

Comment: before `text += ...`, did you define text like this : `var text = ""`? If not, this is your `undefined` at the beginning of `text`.

Comment: lol. Thank you very much. That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make row property to an array, which is easily iterable, at least better than an object with properties?

```
row: ['*-*-*', '**-**', '*-*-*'],
```

If you like to keep the object, you could iterate over the keys

```
['r1', 'r2', 'r3'].forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(gems[1].row[k]) //do something 
});
```

Comment: And if you don't know all the key in your object : `Object.keys(myObject).forEach(...)`

Comment: Thanks Nina, it works as my first loop showed on the post. The output is the same as you can saw in the image above. Perhaps is my fault, but i can't see why `undefined` it is showing again. But your aproach resolve a warning in the editor point me to wrap the function on an `if`statement. So thanks any way. And thanks again because i can saw your are accesing on second member like`row[j]`, thats explain me more!!!!!!.

Answer (score 1):

Your `gems[0].row` returns a object and not an array.

Hence what you want is to loop through a object. Like

```
var arr2 = gems[0].row;

for (var key in arr2 ) {
  text += '<br />' + arr2[key] + '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Conceptualy you are right. because i was using an `arr` variable with some confusing meaning,  but was nothing more that a 'declared' variable, it wasn't initialized!. Thanks any way!

Comment: I like this aproach for simplicity, but i preffer @Nina's aproach because it avoid the editor warning.

Comment: @Hell0 no problem. :)